# scraping text using html agilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am working with a dictionary application which show meaning from English language to Bengali language. I dont have a huge Bangla meaning but i have a huge English word.By using this English words i want to translate into Bengali language using Google translator and thus make my dictionary database. So i scrap the meaning from the google translator.I used the following code:

```
string meaning = "", bangla = "";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://translate.google.com/#en/bn/like");
        HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word']");

        if (node != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode n in node)
            {
                meaning = n.InnerText;
                meaning = meaning.Trim();
                MessageBox.Show(meaning);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry,the meaning is not found");
```

the element was **div.gt-baf-cell.gt-baf-word** on the firebug tool.
But it didn't work here.It shows "Sorry,the meaning is not found".
What is the problem here????

Comment: From what I can see, the name of the div name is "gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word". This is a single string. There isn't a . in between.

Comment: @shahkapesh I also wrote like this "//div[@class='gt-baf-cellgt-baf-word']" but it also didnt work.

Comment: Put space in place of *. -> gt-baf-cell*gt-baf-word

Comment: I also tried this.But the result is same here.

Comment: First, try and see if the page response is **same** as you would see when you type in the url in the browser. i.e. try and log `doc.DocumentNode.InnerText` to Console or a text file to establish the name of the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to do that using HtmlAgilityPack

I tried this:

```
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0";
doc = web.Load("http://translate.google.com/#en/bn/like");
webBrowser1.DocumentText = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

and it gives this result: http://jsbin.com/irijiz/1/edit

As you can see its not the same with what you seeing on your browser, thats why your code not working.

For more information and alternatives check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api)

Comment: your code has nothing wrong, if it was simple site it would work but google seems to have some mechanisms that not allow web scraping.. Check this link for more alternatives solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

Comment: I think those `mechanisms` are simply called JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

Your wrong code is 
HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word']");

because doc.DocumentNode.InnerText doesn't exist div class = gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word

check doc.DocumentNode.InnerText.

why do You try to find "gt-baf-cell gt-baf-word" that doesn't existed?